# Writing uint32 to uint64 is not atomic. Why?

Tags: x86, atomic

In [Is Parallel Programming Hard, And, If So,What Can You Do About It](https://mirrors.edge.kernel.org/pub/linux/kernel/people/paulmck/perfbook/perfbook.2018.12.08a.pdf#page=422) on page 410 it is written:

> Quick Quiz 5.17:
>
> Why doesn’t `inc_count()` in Listing 5.4 need to use atomic instructions?
>
> Answer:
>   (..) atomic instructions would be needed in cases where the
>   per-thread counter variables were smaller than the global global_count
>   (..)

Simplifying, that sentence applies to the following example:

```
uint64 global_count = 0;

void f(){
    uint32 sum = sum_of_smaller_thread_locals(); # sum is a variable 
    WRITE_ONCE(global_count, sum);
}
```

I cannot understand why do we need atomic instructions in that case?

Comment: They're talking the increments in `inc_count`, not about using atomic operations to write `global_count`.  That only needs an atomic operation if you're in 32-bit mode and (on x86) can't use MMX/XMM/x87 registers to do a 64-bit atomic store with `movq` or `fistp` (which is the case in kernel code).  And then only if you care about the atomicity of writing `global_count`.  Then `lock cmpxchg8b` can do a 64-bit store.  But on some (micro)architectures, 64-bit atomic stores can't be done in a lock-free manner, so I don't think that's what they're talking about.

Comment: It doesn't matter where the uint64_t that you're writing to `global_count` comes from, whether it's from zero-extension of a `uint32_t` or whatever.  So your real question is: why does writing to a `uint64_t` require atomic instructions, and the answer is "it doesn't, except on 32-bit platforms".  (Since they're talking about compiler-generated code, you maybe can't count on the compiler using `strd` on ARM for example, even on ARM uarches where it's atomic.)

Comment: That said, I don't understand their point.  If the per-thread counters are still plain `long`, abusing non-`_Atomic` variables with `WRITE_ONCE(*p_counter, *p_counter + 1);` instead of a relaxed-atomic load / increment / relaxed-atomic store will still work in practice on normal CPUs even though it has Data Race UB (from writing while the `eventual()` thread reads also with just `volatile unsigned long*`.)  `volatile` doesn't avoid data-race UB in plain ISO C, although in compilers that can compile Linux, it's known to be safe and is used by the kernel along with inline asm.

Comment: So IDK, maybe they are talking about a global counter that's too wide to be "naturally" atomic?  But it's super weird to word it as the per-thread counters being smaller, instead of the global counter being changed to wider.  Because I think multiple threads are supposed to be reading `global_count`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Peter Cordes points out, the atomic instructions would be required for the per-thread increments.  The reason is given in the text, but the superfluous 'however' clouds it slightly:

> That said, atomic instructions would be needed in cases where the
> per-thread counter variables were smaller than the global global_
> count. <s>However,</s> note that on a 32-bit system, the per-thread counter
> variables might need to be limited to 32 bits in order to sum them
> accurately, but with a 64-bit global_count variable to avoid overflow.
> **In this case, it is necessary to zero the per-thread counter variables
> periodically in order to avoid overflow.** It is extremely important to
> note that this zeroing cannot be delayed too long or overflow of the
> smaller per-thread variables will result. This approach therefore
> imposes real-time requirements on the underlying system, and in turn
> must be used with extreme care.
>
> In contrast, if all variables are the
> same size, overflow of any variable is harmless because the eventual
> sum will be modulo the word size.

If the main thread clears the per-thread counters, it needs to do this via an atomic exchange to avoid possible data loss.  If the per-thread increments do the clearing, to avoid data loss they would need some other (likely more complex) kind of interlock.

Comment: Ah yes, I see what they're getting at now.  Instead of *just* reading the counters, atomically exchange with zero and sum into `global_count`, so at any point the total sum is `global_count` *plus* what's in the per_thread counters. And for this store to not be stepped on (because now there are two writers), the per-thread increments need to use an atomic RMW as well.  (`counter.fetch_add(1)`, i.e. x86 `lock add dword [fs:per_thread_count], 1`) The same applies if you were *just* zeroing with a pure store: the increment still has to be atomic so a store can't happen between load and store.

Comment: That quiz answer does a very poor job of explaining that fundamental change to the algorithm.  It didn't make sense to me to *just* zero the counters like they were saying instead of letting them wrap to zero on their own.